# Stepping with multiple values while slicing an array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, list

I am trying to get *m* values while stepping through every *n* elements of an array. For example, for *m* = 2 and *n* = 5, and given

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

I want to retrieve

```
b = [1, 2, 6, 7]
```

Is there a way to do this using slicing? I can do this using a nested list comprehension, but I was wondering if there was a way to do this using the indices only. For reference, the list comprehension way is:

```
 b = [k for j in [a[i:i+2] for i in range(0,len(a),5)] for k in j]
```

Comment: What should happen when the length of the list leaves a remainder?

Comment: 0 need for explicit version tag, removed

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I agree with wim that you can't do it with just slicing. But you can do it with just one list comprehension:

```
>>> [x for i,x in enumerate(a) if i%n < m]
[1, 2, 6, 7]
```

Comment: Alternatively and without division remainder but along the same line: `[x for i, x in zip(itertools.cycle(range(n)), a) if i < m]`

Answer (score 6):

No, that is not possible with slicing.  Slicing only supports start, stop, and step - there is no way to represent stepping with "groups" of size larger than 1.

Answer (score 5):

In short, no, you cannot. But you can use `itertools` to remove the need for intermediary lists:

```
from itertools import chain, islice

res = list(chain.from_iterable(islice(a, i, i+2) for i in range(0, len(a), 5)))

print(res)

[1, 2, 6, 7]
```

Borrowing @Kevin's logic, if you want a vectorised solution to avoid a `for` loop, you can use 3rd party library `numpy`:

```
import numpy as np

m, n = 2, 5
a = np.array(a)  # convert to numpy array
res = a[np.where(np.arange(a.shape[0]) % n < m)]
```

Answer (score 3):

There are other ways to do it, which all have advantages for some cases, but none are "just slicing".

---

The most general solution is probably to group your input, slice the groups, then flatten the slices back out. One advantage of this solution is that you can do it lazily, without building big intermediate lists, and you can do it to any iterable, including a lazy iterator, not just a list.

```
# from itertools recipes in the docs
def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx"
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return itertools.zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue)
groups = grouper(a, 5)
truncated = (group[:2] for group in groups)
b = [elem for group in truncated for elem in group]
```

And you can convert that into a pretty simple one-liner, although you still need the `grouper` function:

```
b = [elem for group in grouper(a, 5) for elem in group[:2]]
```

---

Another option is to build a list of indices, and use `itemgetter` to grab all the values. This might be more readable for a more complicated function than just "the first 2 of every 5", but it's probably less readable for something as simple as your use:

```
indices = [i for i in range(len(a)) if i%5 < 2]
b = operator.itemgetter(*indices)(a)
```

… which can be turned into a one-liner:

```
b = operator.itemgetter(*[i for i in range(len(a)) if i%5 < 2])(a)
```

---

And you can combine the advantages of the two approaches by writing your own version of `itemgetter` that takes a lazy index iterator—which I won't show, because you can go even better by writing one that takes an index filter function instead:

```
def indexfilter(pred, a):
    return [elem for i, elem in enumerate(a) if pred(i)]
b = indexfilter((lambda i: i%5<2), a)
```

(To make `indexfilter` lazy, just replace the brackets with parens.)

… or, as a one-liner:

```
b = [elem for i, elem in enumerate(a) if i%5<2]
```

I think this last one might be the most readable. And it works with any iterable rather than just lists, and it can be made lazy (again, just replace the brackets with parens). But I still don't think it's *simpler* than your original comprehension, and it's not just slicing.

Answer (score 2):

The question states array, and by that if we are talking about NumPy arrays, we can surely use few obvious NumPy tricks and few not-so obvious ones. We can surely use `slicing` to get a 2D view into the input under certain conditions.

Now, based on the array length, let's call it `l` and `m`, we would have three scenarios :

#### Scenario #1 :`l` is divisible by `n`

We can use slicing and reshaping to get a view into the input array and hence get constant runtime.

Verify the view concept :

```
In [108]: a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])

In [109]: m = 2; n = 5

In [110]: a.reshape(-1,n)[:,:m]
Out[110]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [6, 7]])

In [111]: np.shares_memory(a, a.reshape(-1,n)[:,:m])
Out[111]: True
```

Check timings on a very large array and hence constant runtime claim :

```
In [118]: a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])

In [119]: %timeit a.reshape(-1,n)[:,:m]
1000000 loops, best of 3: 563 ns per loop

In [120]: a = np.arange(10000000)

In [121]: %timeit a.reshape(-1,n)[:,:m]
1000000 loops, best of 3: 564 ns per loop
```

**To get flattened version :**

If we **have** to get a flattened array as output, we just need to use a flattening operation with `.ravel()`, like so -

```
In [127]: a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])

In [128]: m = 2; n = 5

In [129]: a.reshape(-1,n)[:,:m].ravel()
Out[129]: array([1, 2, 6, 7])
```

Timings show that it's not too bad when compared with the other looping and vectorized numpy.where versions from other posts -

```
In [143]: a = np.arange(10000000)

# @Kevin's soln
In [145]: %timeit [x for i,x in enumerate(a) if i%n < m]
1 loop, best of 3: 1.23 s per loop

# @jpp's soln
In [147]: %timeit a[np.where(np.arange(a.shape[0]) % n < m)]
10 loops, best of 3: 145 ms per loop

In [144]: %timeit a.reshape(-1,n)[:,:m].ravel()
100 loops, best of 3: 16.4 ms per loop
```

#### Scenario #2 :`l` is not divisible by `n`, but the groups end with a complete one at the end

We go to the non-obvious NumPy methods with [**`np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided`**](http://www.scipy-lectures.org/advanced/advanced_numpy/#example-fake-dimensions-with-strides) that allows to go beyoond the memory block bounds (hence we need to be careful here to not write into those) to facilitate a solution using `slicing`. The implementation would look something like this -

```
def select_groups(a, m, n):
    a = np.asarray(a)
    strided = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided

    # Get params defining the lengths for slicing and output array shape    
    nrows = len(a)//n
    add0 = len(a)%n
    s = a.strides[0]
    out_shape = nrows+int(add0!=0),m

    # Finally stride, flatten with reshape and slice
    return strided(a, shape=out_shape, strides=(s*n,s))
```

A sample run to verify that the output is a `view` -

```
In [151]: a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13])

In [152]: m = 2; n = 5

In [153]: select_groups(a, m, n)
Out[153]: 
array([[ 1,  2],
       [ 6,  7],
       [11, 12]])

In [154]: np.shares_memory(a, select_groups(a, m, n))
Out[154]: True
```

To get flattened version, append with `.ravel()`.

Let's get some timings comparison -

```
In [158]: a = np.arange(10000003)

In [159]: m = 2; n = 5

# @Kevin's soln
In [161]: %timeit [x for i,x in enumerate(a) if i%n < m]
1 loop, best of 3: 1.24 s per loop

# @jpp's soln
In [162]: %timeit a[np.where(np.arange(a.shape[0]) % n < m)]
10 loops, best of 3: 148 ms per loop

In [160]: %timeit select_groups(a, m=m, n=n)
100000 loops, best of 3: 5.8 µs per loop
```

If we need a flattened version, it's still not too bad -

```
In [163]: %timeit select_groups(a, m=m, n=n).ravel()
100 loops, best of 3: 16.5 ms per loop
```

#### Scenario #3 :`l` is not divisible by `n`,and the groups end with a *incomplete one* at the end

For this case, we would need an extra slicing at the end on top of what we had in the previous method, like so -

```
def select_groups_generic(a, m, n):
    a = np.asarray(a)
    strided = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided

    # Get params defining the lengths for slicing and output array shape    
    nrows = len(a)//n
    add0 = len(a)%n
    lim = m*(nrows) + add0
    s = a.strides[0]
    out_shape = nrows+int(add0!=0),m

    # Finally stride, flatten with reshape and slice
    return strided(a, shape=out_shape, strides=(s*n,s)).reshape(-1)[:lim]
```

Sample run -

```
In [166]: a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11])

In [167]: m = 2; n = 5

In [168]: select_groups_generic(a, m, n)
Out[168]: array([ 1,  2,  6,  7, 11])
```

Timings -

```
In [170]: a = np.arange(10000001)

In [171]: m = 2; n = 5

# @Kevin's soln
In [172]: %timeit [x for i,x in enumerate(a) if i%n < m]
1 loop, best of 3: 1.23 s per loop

# @jpp's soln
In [173]: %timeit a[np.where(np.arange(a.shape[0]) % n < m)]
10 loops, best of 3: 145 ms per loop

In [174]: %timeit select_groups_generic(a, m, n)
100 loops, best of 3: 12.2 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

With itertools you could get an iterator with:

```
from itertools import compress, cycle

a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
n = 5
m = 2

it = compress(a, cycle([1, 1, 0, 0, 0]))
res = list(it)
```

Comment: If you prefer functors over generator expressions: `compress(a, cycle(map(m.__gt__, range(n))))` or even `compress(a, cycle([True] * m + [False] * (n - m)))`

Comment: I prefer generator expressions! I was just pointing `compress` which can be useful for complicated patterns.

Answer (score 0):

I realize that recursion isn't popular, but would something like this work? Also, uncertain if adding recursion to the mix counts as just using slices.

```
def get_elements(A, m, n):
    if(len(A) < m):
        return A
    else:
        return A[:m] + get_elements(A[n:], m, n)
```

A is the array, m and n are defined as in the question. The first if covers the base case, where you have an array with length less than the number of elements you're trying to retrieve, and the second if is the recursive case. I'm somewhat new to python, please forgive my poor understanding of the language if this doesn't work properly, though I tested it and it seems to work fine.